# Creating alias (or something similar) that activates when cd into a specific folder

Tags: bash, shell, composer-php

Is it possible to create aliases when I enter a certain folder?

What I want:

I use `composer` a lot (a PHP package manager), which installs binaries in `./vendor/bin`. I would like to run the binaries directly from `.`.

For example:

```
/path/to/project
 | - composer.json     // dictates dependencies for the project
 | - vendor            // libs folder for composer, is created by composer
 |    | - bin          // if lib has bin, composer creates this folder
 |    |    | phpunit   // binary
 |    |    | phinx     // binary
 |    | - somelib1     // downloaded by composer
 |    | - somelib2     // downloaded by composer
```

Is it possible to get this to work:

```
> cd /path/to/project
> phpunit
```

And get `phpunit` to execute?

Something like "sensing" the `composer.json` file and dynamically find the binaries in `./vendor/bin` and then do something like `alias="./vendor/bin/<binary-name> $@"` automatically?

I use OS X 10.9 and the boxed in **Terminal** app.

Comment: try adding a relative path to your PATH? i.e. `PATH="$PATH:./bin"` Good luck.

Comment: That did it! I didn't know that you could have relative paths in the PATH-variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can [override `cd`](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/d4494213c0ba2f6f7bb974338a81dea1dd0766a4/scripts/cd), `trap my_function DEBUG` to run something on every command, or add a command into `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

These have different behaviour and caveats, and I can't recommend doing any of them for this use case (after having used each of them at some point). They are bad solutions to [X-Y problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

An alternative which is much less likely to break things horribly is to create a **custom function** to do both things:

```
cdp() {
    cd "$@" && phpunit
}
```

Comment: Or you could try something like [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv#usage), which will execute comands defined in a `.env` file when you `cd` into a directory with such a file.